# Why doesn't the method work in the OnMessage event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use WebSocketSharp to write a client, in Start I add the ChangeColor method to the OnMessage event, and the method is executed but not to the end, it does not change the color of the object, although it should. I tried to call the method in Update on button click and it worked correctly. What is the problem?
The server sends correct data, I checked

```
WebSocket ws;
private Renderer objectRenderer;
private Color matColor;
private string reciveData;



private void Start()
{
    objectRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();

    ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");
    ws.Connect();
    ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
    {
        reciveData = e.Data;
        ChangeColor(e.Data); // its dosent work!
    };
}

void Update()
{
    if (ws == null)
        return;

    // its work
    // if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    // {
    //     ChangeColor(reciveData);
    //     objectRenderer.material.color = matColor;
    // }
}

public void ChangeColor(string data)
{
    string[] colors = data.Split(',');
    matColor = new Color()
    {
        r = float.Parse(colors[0]) / 255.0f,
        g = float.Parse(colors[1]) / 255.0f,
        b = float.Parse(colors[2]) / 255.0f,
        a = float.Parse(colors[3]) / 255.0f
    };
    objectRenderer.material.color = matColor;
}
```

Comment: You have to do it after entire message is received. Put change color after the curly brackets.

Comment: Are you values between 0 and 255?  Color takes values between 0 and 1 so whatever your value would be, you need to divide by 255

Comment: Everts, So in the method I divide by 255 ..

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, because the WebSocketSharp callbacks run on a worker thread. Unity does not allow to interact with your `objectRenderer` in any other thread than the main thread.

You can cache the data as you did and process it in `update` method (which is called in main thread).
Use a boolean to tell the `Update` method to call your `ChangeColour` method.

```
WebSocket ws;
private Renderer objectRenderer;
private Color matColor;
private string reciveData;
private bool newDataToBeProcessed;



private void Start()
{
    objectRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();

    ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");
    ws.Connect();
    ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
    {
        reciveData = e.Data;
        newDataToBeProcessed = true;
    };
}

void Update()
{
    if (ws == null)
        return;

    
     if (newDataToBeProcessed == true)
     {
         newDataToBeProcessed = false;
         ChangeColor(reciveData);
         objectRenderer.material.color = matColor; 
     }
}

public void ChangeColor(string data)
{
    string[] colors = data.Split(',');
    matColor = new Color()
    {
        r = float.Parse(colors[0]) / 255.0f,
        g = float.Parse(colors[1]) / 255.0f,
        b = float.Parse(colors[2]) / 255.0f,
        a = float.Parse(colors[3]) / 255.0f
    };
    objectRenderer.material.color = matColor;
}
```

Comment: But how can I call the method after receiving the message and have it change the color of the object? I understand that this is only possible in the main thread, that is, in Update, just how then to track the message and after it call the method without pressing a key in this script?

Comment: Use a boolean to tell the Update method to call your ChangeColour method.